# Is there a simple way to loop through an object who's values are arrays of objects to generate a list from those object's values

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object

I have a JSON object I am importing into a react page that's similar to the following:

```
const obj1 = {
  "January": [
    {
      "Id": 1,
      "FileName": "some file",
      "Format": "Excel (.xlsx)",
      "Category": "some category 1",
      "Start": "01/01/2019",
      "End": "12/31/2019",
      "Created": "01/09/2019"
    },
    {
      "Id": 2,
      "FileName": "some big file",
      "Format": "Excel (.xlsx)",
      "Category": "some category 2",
      "Start": "01/01/2018",
      "End": "12/31/2018",
      "Created": "01/09/2019"
    }
  ],
  "February": [
    {
      "Id": 3,
      "FileName": "some small file",
      "Format": "PDF (.pdf)",
      "Category": "some category 3",
      "Start": "01/01/2018",
      "End": "12/31/2018",
      "Created": "01/09/2019"
    },
    {
      "Id": 4,
      "FileName": "some other file",
      "Format": "Excel (.xlsx)",
      "Category": "some category 4",
      "Start": "01/01/2018",
      "End": "12/31/2018",
      "Created": "01/09/2018"
    }
  ],
  "March": [
    {
      "Id": 55,
      "FileName": "some file again",
      "Format": "Excel (.xlsx)",
      "Category": "some category 5",
      "Start": "01/01/2017",
      "End": "12/31/2017",
      "Created": "01/09/2017"
    }
  ]
};
```

and I want to loop through the above objects and dynamically populate a select dropdown element's options with each unique category.

The select would look something like this:

```
<select className="selectpicker" data-width="fit" value="All" onChange={this.addSomeOptions}>
  <option >Category 1</option>
  <option >Category 2</option>
  <option >Category 3</option>
</select>
```

Is there a good way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: The title is a bit hard to read, do you mean an array which contains arrays of functions which generate a value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try flattening the array and mapping through it to extract values

```
Object.values(obj1).flat().map((a)=> a.Category)
```

You can omit the `flat()` if the array always is one dimensional

Result:

```
["some category 1", "some category 2", "some category 3", "some category 4", "some category 5"]
```

Comment: @BelminBedak No, flatMap is "map then flatten", here we need to flatten first then map.

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly that I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

If `underscore`  is an Option I'd go with:

```
let Categories = [];
for (let x of obj1) {
    Categories.push(x.Category);
}
let uniqueCategories = _.uniqWith(Categories, _.isEqual);
return uniqueCategories;
```